# iOS Sprite Kit Sprite Nodes don't work unless in initWithSize method

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am making an iOS game using SpriteKit and have found that, for some reason, the sprites only respond to actions sent if the actions are sent within the `initWithSize` method.  This is quite infuriating because I am doing the same things outside of the `initWithSize` method that I am inside, so it should work.  For example, I use `[self addChild:playerSprite]` within the `initWithSize` method and it works perfectly.  If I use it anywhere else, it does nothing.  Same code and everything.  I have worked on this issue for hours and cannot find any reason for this.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: That should not be so, can you show the complete code?

Comment: What do you want for "complete code?" The entire document is near 1000 lines of code...  Do you want the `initWithSize` and another method?

Comment: Just the initWithSize method will do for now.

Comment: And more importantly the way you try to run actions where it doesn't work. I'm guessing a nil reference as in [node runAction:..] where node is nil.